# Is there a way to compare the fields from two different queries in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I have a requirement where I need to compare two different Queries related to Different Area Path (Different Projects).

Both the projects are working on the same application and to avoid any object conflict, we are updating UDF field with the Integration# (Example INT-XXX), as part of this comparison, we need to see if there are any INT# where both the projects have some stories logged.

We are using TFS 2017. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such way to achieve this in TFS.

You may build an application to do it through Work item rest API.

Another workaround is exporting all queries and related fields to Excel. Finally use Excel to handle the comparison.

- You can export the query result to Excel from Team Explorer:

  [image]
- Another way is saving the query from Web Portal, then create report
  from Excel directly by clicking `Team` tab and go to `New List` to
  connect the team project and select the saved query result:

  [image]

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I am already using Excel to generate the required report. But I will surely give a try to REST API.